# Why report is shrunk When RDLC Report is printed directly to POS printer

Tags: c#, printing, report, rdlc

i am trying to print an `RDLC` Report Directly to a POS Printer, using source code from MSDN ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)), by exporting the report to (`EMF`) Image, then printing the image to the printer using `PrintDocument`,I calculate the height of the report based on number of rows (height of one row = 0.6 cm).

The problem is that when the report is too long (more than one page), I got its rows shrunk (compressed) to each other.

How to solve this problem ?
Do I have to use POS Printer library (.NET POS) instead of the exporting the report to image and printing the image? .
you can download the source code from ([Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/UploadFile/houssam11350/12212012184019PM/exportrdlcreport.rar)).

thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another solution is to print the large image (which I export the report to it) to many pages :

```
private void PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
        {
            if (pageImage == null)
                return;
            ev.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            ev.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            ev.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            float a = (ev.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width / 100) * ev.Graphics.DpiX;
            float b = ((ev.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height / 100) * ev.Graphics.DpiY);
            float scale = 1500;
            scale = 0;
            RectangleF srcRect = new RectangleF(0, startY, pageImage.Width, b - scale);
            RectangleF destRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, a, b);
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            startY = startY + b - scale;
            float marignInPixel = (0.5f / 2.54f) * ev.Graphics.DpiY;
            ev.HasMorePages = (startY + marignInPixel < pageImage.Height);
        }
```

you can download the source code from ([here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/UploadFile/houssam11350/12222012095334AM/exportrdlcreport_update_2.rar))

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the size of the paper :

```
PaperSize pkCustomSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom Paper Size", Convert.ToInt32((WidthInInCM / 2.54) * 100), Convert.ToInt32((HeightInInCM / 2.54) * 100));
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;

            if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            {
                String msg = String.Format("Can't find printer \"{0}\".", PrinterName);
                MessageBox.Show(msg, "Print Error");
                return;
            }
            printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize;
            printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins;
```

you can download the updated source code from ([here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/UploadFile/houssam11350/12222012095334AM/exportrdlcreport_updated.rar)).

Comment: Can you please merge both solutions into a single answer and accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: @Ryan Gates : thanks for your comment, I cannot merge both solutions because they are different, but I will accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck on a similiar problem.

I've managed to fix it using the following:

```
    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {

        Metafile pageImage =
          new Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);
//That's the fix - Units set to Display
        ev.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Display;
//Drawing it scaled
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, 0, 0, ev.MarginBounds.Width, ev.MarginBounds.Height);

        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);            
    }
```

The page gets drawn to printer canvas scaled.